# In CakePHP, is there a better way to use AES_DECRYPT?

Tags: mysql, cakephp, aes, cakephp-2.4

I have some data stored in a table that was encrypted using AES_ENCRYPT.  I am using a CakePHP application to decrypt this information for use.  Currently I have resorted to building an SQL statement and storing it in $query and using:

```
$results = $this->query($query);
```

While this works, I was wondering if there is a more Cake like way to accomplish this without resorting to manually writing the SQL queries.

Answer (score 0):

Put something like this in your afterFind method:

```
    function afterFind($results, $primary = false) {

    if($primary == true){

        foreach($results as $resultKey => $resultValue) {

            $results[$resultKey][$this->alias]['decrypted'] = Security::decrypt ( $results[$resultKey][$this->alias]['encrypted'], $key, $hmacSalt );
        }
    }

    return $results;
}
```

Here is the [documentation for the AES decryption routines.](http://api.cakephp.org/2.5/class-Security.html#_decrypt)

Alternatively you can use a [virtual field](http://api.cakephp.org/2.5/class-Model.html#%24virtualFields) to do the same thing.

Comment: I am a little confused as your link points to the Cake API version 2.5 which doesn't seem to be available as a link from the main CakePHP website.  Looking at the API version 2.4 documentation I don't see the  Security::encrypt and Security::decrypt methods.  When I try your code I am getting the Error: Call to undefined method Security::decrypt().  Are these methods coming in a future release or am I missing something?  I am currently running Cake 2.4.2.

Comment: Hmm you're right, they're not available in 2.4.  Until then, there is always this little snippet: http://bin.cakephp.org/saved/52840 (note the base64 encoding, you may need to remove this). Alternatively, if you already have some SQL that will decrypt your data, then setting up a virtual field might be easier.